# Respond to JSON is responding via HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller

In my Rails app, I have in the Application controller

```
respond_to :json
```

A controller that inherits Application controller responds with json like so in the action...

```
  # Some code

  if mission_updated.eql? true
    render :json => {}
  else
    render :json => {}
  end
```

However, whenever I run a rspec test in reference to the above action

```
  it "should return appropriate response" do
    post :update_unlocked_missions

    parsed_body = JSON.parse(response.body)

    parsed_body.should == {}
  end
```

I'm returned with the following rspec error

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template api/v1/missions/update_unlocked_missions, api/v1/base/update_unlocked_missions with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :rabl, :haml]}. Searched in:
         * "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0x007f9ea2903b00>"
```

My question is why is it going to the view when it should respond with json and how do I fix this?

Comment: If you have a controller action whose body is nothing but `render :json => {}`, does that return what you expect?

Comment: And another idea: try it with `render json: {}, layout: false`...although it doesn't seem like you should have to explicitly tell it not to use a layout.

Comment: The former suggestion works. I'm returned an empty json. I guess now I have to figure out why my code in my action is producing a view.

Comment: Seems like it would have to be something in `mission_updated`. I bet if you changed your controller's `if` to just `if true` or `if false` it would work.

Comment: Ahh, although not the exact fix you helped me solve the problem. I had the respond_to in a loop, long story short the loop was preventing the respond_to from being called. Update your answer if you want.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer. I'm not sure if my update matches what actually fixed your problem, but at least it's probably closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try testing with an action that's just `render json: {}`. If that works, the problem is probably something in `mission_updated`.